# Show that $R$ is a Noetherian Ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, finitely-generated, noetherian

$R$ is a ring and $I$ is a finitely generated nilpotent ideal. If $R/I$ is noetherian show that $R$ is noetherian.

Comment: @Babgen: I apologize if this sounds a bit harsh, but the edit made this question worse. It was fine as is.

Comment: Ok, its better now, but it is still much more typical to write $R/I$ that it is to write $\frac{R}{I}$. In fact, I have never seen the second notation.

Comment: @rghthndsd there is no different. Both of symbols are used, but if you like the second then I will use the second one.

Comment: @Babgen In general, one should avoid [changing the notation](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11857/arbitrarily-editing-an-askers-notation-to-fit-your-own-preferences) of the original question, IMHO.

Comment: Does anyone know why this question is on hold?

Comment: @user114539 See below: *Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it.* This is the template that best fits questions where the closers would like additional work to be done by the poster.

Answer (score 3):

Since $I$ is nilpotent and finitely generated, there exists $n$ such that $I^n = 0$. It thus suffices to show that $R/I^k$ is a Noetherian $R$-module for every $k$, which can be done by induction.

For $k = 1$, note that $R/I$ is Noetherian as an $R/I$-module, hence also as an $R$-module (the module structures are the same). Next, notice that for every $k$, $I^k/I^{k+1}$ is finitely generated and has $R$-annihilator equal to $I$, and is thus a Noetherian $R$-module. Finally, there is a short exact sequence of $R$-modules

$$0 \to I^k/I^{k+1} \to R/I^{k+1} \to R/I^k \to 0$$

The first term is always Noetherian, and the last term is Noetherian by induction, so the middle term is Noetherian as well.

Answer (score 2):

By Cohen's theorem, $R$ is Noetherian iff all its prime ideals are finitely generated.

Since $I$ is nilpotent, the prime ideals of $R/I$ correspond to those of $R$ via the projection $R\to R/I$, and are of the form $P/I$ for various primes $P$. We make use of this last fact to show that all the $P$ are finitely generated $R$ ideals.

Let $p$ be in prime $P$. Since $P/I$ is finitely generated $R/I$ module, there is a set of $\{x_i+I\mid 1\leq i\leq n\}\subseteq P/I$ such that $p+I=\sum (x_i+I)(r_i+I)$ mod $I$, for some $r_i\in R$, i.e. $p-\sum x_ir_i\in I$.

Using a finite generating set $\{y_j\mid1\leq j\leq m\}$ for $I$ as an $R$ module, we then have that $p-\sum x_ir_i=\sum y_js_j\in I$ for some $s_j\in R$. Rearranging, we get that $p=\sum x_ir_i + \sum y_js_j$. This demonstrates that the $x_i$s and the $y_j$s together generate $P$ as an $R$-module.

By Cohen's theorem, we're done.

Comment: This is the first thing that occurred to me... am I overlooking something?

Comment: Maybe you missed the following ses: $0\to I\to P\to P/I\to 0$ where the extremities are f.g. (as ideals or $R$-modules, is the same), so $P$ is also f.g.

Comment: @user121097 "ses"? That observation is just a repackaging of the result of these details, right?

Comment: @user121097 oh, "short exact sequence." I am 100% sure I've never seen someone abbreviate that way before :) I'm definitely not fluent with facts about short exact sequences.

Comment: @rschwieb, The use of Cohen's thm is nice and makes the proof short, SES helps make it shorter. Do you know why this question is on hold? What is wrong with it?

Comment: @user114539 Thanks. Based on the closure message above, I think it was closed because of perceived lack of effort on the OP's part.